# Using AFNetworking NSOperations to download a number of files serially.....runs out of memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, automatic-ref-counting, out-of-memory

Note: I'm using ARC.

I have some code that makes 1 request to an http server for a list of files (via JSON). It then parses that list into model objects which it uses to add a download operation (for downloading that file) to a different nsoperationqueue and then once it's done adding all of those operations (queue starts out suspended) it kicks off the queue and waits for all the operations to finish before continuing. (Note: this is all done on background threads so as not to block the main thread).

Here's the basic code:

```
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:parseServiceUrl];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    //NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

    // Parse JSON into model objects

    NSNumber* results = [responseObject objectForKey:@"results"];
    if ([results intValue] > 0)
    {
        dispatch_async(_processQueue, ^{

            _totalFiles = [results intValue];
            _timestamp = [responseObject objectForKey:@"timestamp"];
            NSArray* files = [responseObject objectForKey:@"files"];

            for (NSDictionary* fileDict in files)
            {
                DownloadableFile* file = [[DownloadableFile alloc] init];
                file.file_id = [fileDict objectForKey:@"file_id"];
                file.file_location = [fileDict objectForKey:@"file_location"];
                file.timestamp = [fileDict objectForKey:@"timestamp"];
                file.orderInQueue = [files indexOfObject:fileDict];

                NSNumber* action = [fileDict objectForKey:@"action"];
                if ([action intValue] >= 1)
                {
                    if ([file.file_location.lastPathComponent.pathExtension isEqualToString:@""])
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    [self downloadSingleFile:file];
                }
                else // action == 0 so DELETE file if it exists
                {
                    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:file.localPath])
                    {
                        NSError* error;
                        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:file.localPath error:&error];
                        if (error)
                        {
                            NSLog(@"Error deleting file after given an Action of 0: %@: %@", file.file_location, error);
                        }
                    }
                }

                [self updateProgress:[files indexOfObject:fileDict] withTotal:[files count]];

            }

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [_label setText:@"Syncing Files..."];
            });

            [_dlQueue setSuspended:NO];
            [_dlQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];

            [SettingsManager sharedInstance].timestamp = _timestamp;

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                callback(nil);
            });
        });
    }
    else
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            callback(nil);
        });
    }


} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    callback(error);
}];

[_parseQueue addOperation:op];
```

and then the downloadSingleFile method:

```
- (void)downloadSingleFile:(DownloadableFile*)dfile
{
NSURLRequest* req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:dfile.downloadUrl];

AFHTTPRequestOperation* reqOper = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:req];
reqOper.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

[reqOper setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation* op, id response)
 {
         __weak NSData* fileData = response;
         NSError* error;

         __weak DownloadableFile* file = dfile;

         NSString* fullPath = [file.localPath substringToIndex:[file.localPath rangeOfString:file.localPath.lastPathComponent options:NSBackwardsSearch].location];
         [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:fullPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:Nil error:&error];
         if (error)
         {
             NSLog(@"Error creating directory path: %@: %@", fullPath, error);
         }
         else
         {
             error = nil;
             [fileData writeToFile:file.localPath options:NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete error:&error];
             if (error)
             {
                 NSLog(@"Error writing fileData for file: %@: %@", file.file_location, error);
             }
         }

         [self updateProgress:file.orderInQueue withTotal:_totalFiles];
 }
                               failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation* op, NSError* error)
 {
     [self updateProgress:dfile.orderInQueue withTotal:_totalFiles];
     NSLog(@"Error downloading %@: %@", dfile.downloadUrl, error.localizedDescription);
 }];

[_dlQueue addOperation:reqOper];
}
```

What I'm seeing is a constant spike in memory as more files get downloaded. It's like the responseObject or maybe even the whole completionBlock is not being let go of.

I've tried making the responseObject __weak as well as fileData. I've tried adding an autoreleasepool and I've tried making the actual file domain object __weak too but still memory climbs and climbs.

I've run Instruments and not seen any leaks persay but it never gets to a point where all the files have been downloaded before it runs out of memory with a big fat "can't allocate region" error. Looking at allocations, I see a bunch of connection:didFinishLoading and connection:didReceiveData methods that never seem to be let go of, however. I can't seem to debug it further than that though.

**My question: Why is it running out of memory? What is not getting deallocated and how can I get it to do such?**

Comment: Someone on twitter mentioned that self is being retained because I'm using [self updateProgress] so it's retaining the controller inside the completion block which is owned by the operation which is owned by the operationqueue which is owned by the controller.....so there's the retain cycle. I'll have to see what happens when I move the [self updateProgress] code into the block directly instead.

Comment: Note that removing [self updateProgress] did not solve the problem either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of a friend, I was able to figure out the problem.

The problem was actually in the first block of code:

```
[_dlQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
```

Apparently , waiting for all operations to finish meant none of those operations would be released either.

Instead of that, I ended up adding a final operation to the queue that would do the final processing and callback and memory is much more stable now.

```
[_dlQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
                    [SettingsManager sharedInstance].timestamp = _timestamp;

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        callback(nil);
                    });
                }];
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a few things going on here. The biggest is that you are downloading the entire file, storing it in memory, and then writing it out to disk when the download is complete. Even with just one file of 500 MB, you will run out of memory.

The correct way to do this is using an NSOutputStream with asynchronous downloads. The key is to write out the data as soon as it arrives. It should look like this:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
}
```

Also of note, you are creating your weak references inside the block, not outside. Because of that, you are still creating a retain cycle and leaking memory. When you create weak references, it should look like this.

```
NSOperation *op = [[NSOperation alloc] init];
__weak NSOperation *weakOp = op;
op.completion = ^{
    // Use only weakOp within this block
};
```

Lastly, your code is using `@autoreleasepool`. NSAutoreleasePool, and the ARC equivalent `@autoreleasepool` are only useful in very limited situations. As a general rule, if you aren't absolutely sure you need one, you don't.

Comment: Great answer with three best practices suggestions!

Comment: Thanks. I know about using NSOutputstream but I need to write the data to disk using File Protection for security reasons.

Comment: Also the __weak and autoreleasepool areas in the code are areas where I was experimenting trying to see if making some things weak made any difference or if the autoreleasepool made any difference to get whatever it is that's being retained...released. None of the combinations worked however, including the way you suggested here.

Comment: "It didn't work" is not helpful diagnostically. What did or did not happen that you were expecting? We can't help if we don't have enough information.

Comment: What didn't happen is the problem wasn't solved. The memory still kept going up without ever releasing. The code I posted here was after modifying a bunch of places with __weak and autoreleasepool. I should probably just put it back to the way it was before I started experimenting with that.

Also when I created __weak references outside of the completion block, they were already released when the block was executed....so they were useless

Comment: I'm torn right now between using this as a great learning experience for you and for others that might read this is the future or just showing you the right way and hoping you figure out the "why" of what I did on your own. Since this is your question, I'll leave the choice up to you. What is your preference?

Comment: My preference is to be enlightened rather than beat my head against the wall trying to figure it out ;)

Comment: I'd also love to know how to make use of the Outputstream instead of reading the data into memory but still be able to write that stream using File protection

Answer (score 0):

What kind of file you are downloading? If you are working with Images or videos you nee to clear URLCache as when you doneload images it create CFDATA and some information in cache and it does not cleared out. You need to clear it explicitly when your single file download completed. It will never caught as a leak also.

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
    [sharedCache release];

If you are using ARC replace 
    [sharedCache release];
with
    sharedCache = nil;
```

Hope It may help you.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. Some are images, some are word documents, some are HTML files, movies, etc.